# SQL query to display a date and count based on conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to display as the below mine is like using two queries I want to display my query

```
select * from 
(
   select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dialdate, 105)  as toc, 
          count(endtime) as 'TotalNoOfCalls' 
   from processeddata_table 
   where DialDate between '2012-03-03' 
         and '2014-04-14'  
         and endtime!= '' 
         and toc != ''  
         and adjustedduration !='00:00:00' 
         and toc like 'voip%' 
         and endtime='Comverse'
   group by dialdate 
)  processeddata_table 
union 
   select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dialdate, 105) as toc, 
          count(endtime) as 'TotalNoOfCalls' 
   from processeddata_table
   where DialDate between '2012-03-03' 
         and '2014-04-14'  
         and endtime!= '' 
         and toc != ''  
         and adjustedduration !='00:00:00' 
         and (endtime='Bharthi ' or endtime='TATA') 
         and (toc = 'STD' 
           or toc = 'ISD' 
           or toc = 'LOCAL' 
           or toc = 'Unmatured'  
           or toc = 'TOLL' 
           or toc = 'ACB' 
           or toc = 'ACB-IN' 
           or toc = 'BTB' 
           or toc = 'INCOMING') 
     group by dialdate
```

OUTPUT:

```
Date         Total

04-04-2014     2

04-04-2014     1
```

I NEED RESULT AS:

```
Date         Total

04-04-2014     3
```

Comment: PLease edit your question and use proper formatting for better readability. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `WHERE` clause you should be able to get this in just one query.

I might have some mismatched brackets and I have not listed all endtimes but you get the idea.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dialdate, 105) as toc, 
      count(endtime) as 'TotalNoOfCalls' 
from processeddata_table
where DialDate between '2012-03-03' 
     and '2014-04-14'  
     and endtime!= '' 
     and toc != ''  
     and adjustedduration !='00:00:00' 
     and (
     (endtime='Comverse')
     OR         
     (endtime IN ('Bharthi ','TATA') 
     and (toc IN ('STD' ,'ISD' , 'Comverse',...))
     ) )
 group by dialdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the where clauses as ElectricLlama mentioned.

Another way is to select the raw values and embed that query in a subquery and use aggregation on that subquery.

```
select
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dialdate, 105)  as toc, 
    count(endtime) AS TotalNoOfCalls
from 
(
        select
            dialdate, 
            endtime
        from
            processeddata_table 
        where
            DialDate between '2012-03-03' 
            and '2014-04-14'  
            and endtime!= '' 
            and toc != ''  
            and adjustedduration !='00:00:00' 
            and toc like 'voip%' 
            and endtime='Comverse'

    union 

        select
            dialdate, 
            endtime
        from
            processeddata_table
        where
            DialDate between '2012-03-03' 
            and '2014-04-14'  
            and endtime!= '' 
            and toc != ''  
            and adjustedduration !='00:00:00' 
            and (endtime='Bharthi ' or endtime='TATA') 
            and (
                -- Use IN instead of endless ORs
                toc = 'STD' 
                or toc = 'ISD' 
                or toc = 'LOCAL' 
                or toc = 'Unmatured'  
                or toc = 'TOLL' 
                or toc = 'ACB' 
                or toc = 'ACB-IN' 
                or toc = 'BTB' 
                or toc = 'INCOMING'
            )
    ) DATA
group by
    dialdate
```